# How to do a query in CDbCriteria with Not Exists clause?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need to do the following query in Yii and I like to use a criteria:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
where t1.nome like '%somestring%'
and not exists (select 1 from table2 t2
where t2.table1_id = t1.id and t2.some_id in (15,22,1987));
```

I didn't find a way to add the "not exists" clause in Yii CDbCriteria.

Comment: not exists or not in ?

Comment: not exists. The "not in" I know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the question the following way. It's not very beautiful, but it works. :)

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('t2.some_id', $array_values);

$sql = "  select t1.* from table1 t1";
$sql .= " where t1.name like \"%".$string."%\" ";
$sql .= " and not exists (select 1 from table2 t2";
$sql .= " where t2.table1_id = t1.id and " . $criteria->condition . ")";

$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);

$result = $command->queryAll(true, $criteria->params);
```

Answer (score 3):

Where is no standart method for the `NOT EXISTS`. You should use `CDbExpression` class to add condition to criteria:

```
$criteria->addCondition(new CDbExpression("not exists (select 1 from table2 t2
where t2.table1_id = t1.id and t2.some_id in (15,22,1987))"));
```